# why the format is changing when merge 2 documents using "docxcompose"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I use the below code to merge 2 or more documents to get into one document. My documents contain different font styles, font sizes, tables, data, etc. I would say it is a report containing different styles and bulletins etc. All I try to do is just combine. But when I combine it disrupts the art styles and font and literally everything.

```
from docx import Document
from docxcompose.composer import Composer

master = Document("out.docx")
composer = Composer(master)
doc1 = Document("docx\start.docx")
doc2 = Document("docx\conclusion.docx")
composer.append(doc1)
composer.append(doc2)
master.save("out.docx")
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is a mistake....

https://pypi.org/project/docxcompose/

just use the first code from here it should definitely work

Comment: What was the mistake? I'm seeing the same issue